# Multiple DynamoDB GSI additions/deletions and CI/CD pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, continuous-deployment

1. Any change that happens gets pushed to production with a release tag
2. We use Serverless framework for the development

Recently we added 3 GSI's to a DynamoDB table and when run through the CI/CD pipeline it says:

```
Cannot perform more than one GSI creation or deletion in a single update.
```

Suggested Solution

> A workaround would be to break up your changes to only perform one GSI
> update at a time.

For example, if you need to add a GSI and also remove one in a table, try the following:

1. Add the first GSI and run serverless deploy
2. Wait for the GSI to be created and for it to show an Activestatus
3. Remove the second GSI and run serverless deployagain

How should it happen through a CI/CD pipeline though? This is what our table definition in SLS framework looks like:

```
tableUsers:
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table 
Properties: 
  TableName: users-${self:provider.stage} 
AttributeDefinitions: BLA BLA BLA 
BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST 
GlobalSecondaryIndexes:        
   - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi1.name}
```

Let's say we worked on a codebase for months that added 3 different GSIs. When it's time to release, As suggested to do one index at a time, Is it that in step 1, we should change the definition to

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
 - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi1.name} 
 - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi2.name}
```

instead of

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
 - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi1.name} 
 - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi2.name}
 - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi3.name} 
 - IndexName: ${self:custom.tableUsers.gsi4.name}
```

What about the fact that the queries will be referring to gs3 in the codebase still? I do not think removing them in the codebase for deployment would be a good way to do it? Also, what about the fact that we increment versions on every release?
Is there a better way to do it instead?

Comment: First of all, as you're aware it is not possible to add multiple GSIs in a single update (it is possible on creation, but the assumption is your table already exists in the release version, and you want to add multiple GSIs to it). A solution, as you're aware, is to add them one at a time. This is not brilliant but it's a limitation you simply have to be aware of and therefore cater for, potentially doing as you suggested.

Comment: Another way might be to create a lambda-backed custom resource which creates/updates/deletes tables for you, rather than using the actual `AWS::DynamoDB::Table` type. In your custom resource, you would interpret the fields as appropriate, and when it comes to the defined GSIs, you would call the UpdateTable API multiple times sequentially, once per index. That would allow you to accomplish this in a single update. Custom resources can be a little more complex but they can do practically anything you want, so are very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

In general, continuous delivery best practice is to limit the size and complexity of your deployments (and instead, do frequent, small deployments).

When applied to Serverless, this means you should consider deploying new infrastructure separately from application code. This behavior would prevent this issue, and other limitations which are not always apparent but nonetheless crop up.

Consider deploying schema changes to your tables in a separate deployment from the application code. Then, once you've verified that the indices have been created successfully, you can easily add new queries for those indices.